# unable to use sql built in functions in PYODBC SQL Query from Lotus Note DB

Tags: python, sql, database, lotus-notes, pyodbc

I am new to using 'pyodbc' for querying data from ODBC DB. Specifically a Lotus Notes DB.

This is an example where the query fails using a function in SQL:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Lotus Notes SQL Driver (*.nsf)};SERVER=server;DATABASE=db.nsf;PWD=xxxxx;UID=userid", autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sql_addon = """SELECT REPLACE(timestamp_DT,'-','') as timestamp_DT
FROM ViewInNoteDB
"""

df_addon = pd.read_sql(sql_addon, cnxn)
```

This the error I get:

```
': ('37000', u"[37000] [Lotus][ODBC Lotus Notes]Name, constant, or expression expected (23008) (SQLExecDirectW); [37000] [Lotus][ODBC Lotus Notes]Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT' (23064)")
```

I get different errors using GETDATE(), CONVERT function, and many other functions.

Comment: Does `SELECT timestamp_DT FROM ViewInNoteDB` work? If so, how about `SELECT REPLACE(timestamp_DT,'-','') as expr1 FROM ViewInNoteDB` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson when I run `SELECT timestamp_DT FROM ViewInNoteDB`, this is the error I get: `': ('S0022', u'[S0022] [Lotus][ODBC Lotus Notes]Column not found - timestamp_DT (23340) (SQLExecDirectW)')`. The second query gets me this error `': ('37000', u"[37000] [Lotus][ODBC Lotus Notes]Name, constant, or expression expected (23008) (SQLExecDirectW); [37000] [Lotus][ODBC Lotus Notes]Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT' (23064)")`

Comment: "Column not found - timestamp_DT" tells you that the table/view named "ViewInNoteDB" apparently does not contain a column with that name. Check the table/view definition to see what the actual column names are.

Comment: @GordThompson However I am not selecting a column name, I just want the current time. I tried `GETDATE()`, it's not working. No function works including REPLACE(), CONVERT, and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is related to using to SQL*Server syntax which is not supported by the Lotus Notes ODBC driver. CAST and CONVERT are not supported unfortunately.

The only supported column functions: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/notessql/2.0.6/notessql.nsf/66208c256b4136a2852563c000646f8c/1f3d9225b5e6a547852567010067254d?OpenDocument